# Get min value of a class reference field from a list of class references in R

Tags: r, for-loop

R Beginner here.

I have a list of class references. Each class has a field, "x". I want to find the class reference which has the lowest "x" in the list.

In python I would do this:

```
return min(item.x for item in myList)
```

I'm not sure if there is specific terminology for the type of statement above (if someone knows I would like to know), but is there are way of doing a similar type of thing in R ?

If not, what would be the best way to achieve this in R ?

** Edit re. Justins comment

Here is how the list is created ..

```
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
    mylist <- c(mylist, MyClass$new())
}
```

where:

```
MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass",
                        fields = list(x = "numeric"),
                        methods = list(
                           initialize = function(){
                               x <<- sample(0:100, 1)
                           }
                        )
)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share a portion of your data with us? use `dput`.  Otherwise, its hard to tell what type of data structure you're working with and the answer will vary accordingly. Something like `min(unlist(lapply(myList, function(y) y$x)))` might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get to the entire instance of MyClass with the lowest value of x, as opposed to just the minimum value of x (you seem to be looking for the former), consider using `which.min` in something like the following:

```
mylist[[which.min(lapply(mylist, function(myClass) myClass$x))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is just a list which can be accessed using its named components:

```
> mylist[[1]]$x
[1] 66
>
```

so the answer in my comment will work:

```
> min(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(y) y$x)))
[1] 20
```

I'll leave the details to someone who knows R's OO better than I do...